# WIndows XP vs Windows 8 VPN speed

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, vpn, speedtest

When connecting to a VPN using Windows XP I'm noticing my speedtest.net download rate tops out at 3-4Mbps while using Windows 8.1 I'm noticing speeds that are in excess of 15Mbps. I've even achieved 21Mbps.

Some things I've tried.

1. I connecting directly to my cable modem, without a router.
2. Changing the PPTP settings in Windows XP to mirror those in Windows 8.1
3. Using several Chrome, Firefox and IE to see if the speedtest was being influenced by the browser.

Unfortunately none of these changes has resulted in speeds that are any better. As the Windows 8.1 machine is considerable faster. I've posted various speedtest results for others to review, but haven't had much luck.

Any help in tracking down this discrepancy would be appreciated.

Comment: Two different machines? Hardware differences accounting for the difference?

Comment: I don't believe so. I've connected both machines directly to the cable modem using a cat5 cable. Both network cards are 10/100. I can imagine some variation in speed between the two, but nothing so great.

Comment: You are connecting windows XP to the internet? Now that it has passed end of life and has known unpatched vulnerabilities?

Comment: I'm having the same issues when connecting to the VPN using a DD-WRT equipped router. I figured I'd make it a Windows question, because testing using XP is a lot easier.